# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: Response payload is not completed

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

It works perfectly fine with requests however I am getting "aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: Response payload is not completed" while using asyncio and aiohttp for the website https://www.nslchemicals.com.sg.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'https://www.nslchemicals.com.sg')
        print(html[:10])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

*lib versions*
asyncio==3.4.3
aiohttp==3.6.2

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Network issues?

Comment: also have error from this code